# Assistance in creating formula to replace variables

Tags: r, function, syntax, formula

I have a dataset like this:

```
db <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), female = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Where female=1 means that the patient is female, female=0 means is male.

Then, I have this formula.
Suppose x=frequency of females in group 1, y=frequency of females in group 2 [which I calculated manually]

```
formula <- function(x,y){
  x <- x/100 #frequency should not be expressed as percentage but :100
  y <- y/100
  z <- x*(1-x)
  t <- y*(1-y)
  k <- sum(z,t)
  l <- k/2
  
return((x-y)/sqrt(l))
  
}
```

Instead of writing manually the frequency, for example, of females in group 1 (x) and in group 2 (y), I would like to change this function so that I can write something like:
`formula(db$female, db$group)` and automatically in this formula R calculates the frequency of females and uses it in the formula

Comment: In group 1, there are 2 females and 1 male. What should `x` be? `2/100 = 0.02` or `2/(2+1) = 0.66`? The latter makes more sense for me.

Comment: @Darren It would be the latter, 0.66 I divided x per 100 because x was thought to be 0.66x100 as in baseline tables so I could write 6.66 and the function would convert it correctly into 0.66

Comment: @DarrenTsai  It would be the latter, 0.66 I divided x per 100 because x was thought to be 0.66x100 as in baseline tables so I could write 6.66 and the function would convert it correctly into 0.66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of the problem, I have slightly modified the function, this should work as described, provided the groups are either 1 or 2.

```
formula <- function(input1, input2){
  
  x <- sum(input1[input2 == 1]) / length(input1[input2 == 1])
  y <- sum(input1[input2 == 2]) / length(input1[input2 == 2])
  
  x <- x/100 #frequency should not be expressed as percentage but :100
  y <- y/100
  z <- x*(1-x)
  t <- y*(1-y)
  k <- sum(z,t)
  l <- k/2
  
  return((x-y)/sqrt(l))
}
```

Due to `x` and `y` appearing multiple times, and to avoid confusion, I have changed the arguments of the function to `input1` and `input2`.

Comment: Thank you but the formula above produces a different result and I don't understand why. Let's suppose that the frequency of females in group 1 is 0.66 and in group 2 is 0.50. With my formula, the result is: 0.2264554. With your formula -0.009936853 [I wrote: db$female, db$group]

Comment: By deleting the part of the code x<- x/100 and y<-y/100 which I suppose is the one that causes problems, the result is still different in your formula: -0.1841149

Comment: I think it might be due to approximation

Comment: @user19745561 I am unable to get the result of 0.2264554 using your original formula though. If I use your original function and the inputs of 0.66 and 0.5, i.e., `formula(0.66, 0.5)`, I get 0.02107139. Can you share more details so I can see what part(s) I might have done incorrectly?

Comment: You are right, it was a typo. Anyway I tried with different datasets and I obtained the same results, I think the slight discrepancy is due to the approximation :) Thank you so much!